# Bash variable including "<<EOF"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sftp, heredoc

I am trying to make a function in bash to automatize sftp. Something like:

```
sftp host:dir <<EOF
put afile.txt
exit
EOF
```

The problem is I need the last part as a variable. So something like:

```
file="<<EOF
put afile.txt
exit
EOF"
```

so I can use it like

```
stfp host:dir $file
```

This clearly doesn't work. I have two problems I don't know to solve:
making the variable **$file** in one line and adding the variable to the command.

Any help would be appreciated

PS: Sorry for being picky. I have tried the options with `echo -n $var | stfp`  and `sftp -b script_file`. But I am looking for something that takes an argument in the latest position and could be written in one line.

Comment: Option `-b` (Batch mode) might help.

Comment: Variable expansions aren't parsed as syntax, so it doesn't matter if you can put `<<EOF` in a variable -- even if you do, it won't mean the same thing to the shell that it meant if it was parsed as source code.

Comment: Put the data in a file; redirect standard input from the file (make sure the file gets cleaned up afterwards, and if anything goes wrong).  The here-document basically does that — puts the material in the here-document into a file that is given as standard input to the process.

Comment: A herestring is really the sanest approach -- put _only the literal data_, not the surrounding syntax, in a variable; and then use `<<<"$that_variable"`.

Comment: ...the reason putting `<<EOF` in a variable doesn't work is the same way putting quotes in a variable doesn't work to make running that variable the same as running code containing those same quotes as syntax -- a limitation discussed in detail in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: `stfp host:dir "$file"` would work fine if he prefixed it with a command beginning with "e".

Comment: `echo -n $var` has its own bugs; you need to quote to make it work correctly (`echo -n "$var"` could work though it's better not to use the `-n`; but big-picture, when you leave out the quotes, `echo -n $var` throws away newlines, expands globs, and does other things you don't want)

Comment: @OddKviteberg, re: [your recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68184448/3) ("Sorry for being picky"), do note the links above. _There exists no possible content_ that can be stored in the variable named `file` that will make `sftp host:dir $file` write an arbitrary string to stdin of `sftp`. You're going to need to focus more on your desired outcome, and less on your desired mechanism to get there.

Comment: @OddKviteberg, ...to provide a terser explanation of why that's true, see the [BashParser](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) wiki page. Note that `$file` is only replaced with the variable's content in step 5 of the parser, which means that steps 1-4 can't see the result of such replacements. (This is a good thing, really -- bash could never handle untrusted data safely if such data could be silently/unintentionally interpreted as code; as for _explicitly, intentionally_ interpreting data as code, see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well the solution you proposed was almost what I am looking for. The issues I am facing now is how to include the  operator "<<<" in the variable.

Comment: @OddKviteberg, once again, you _can't_, intentionally; if you could do that, bash would be completely unsuited to writing code that handles untrusted data. If you want to store syntax under a name, that's what functions are for.

Comment: @OddKviteberg, ...mind, you can certainly can write `with_sftp_script() { "$@" <<<$'put afile.txt\nexit\n'; }`, and then call `with_sftp_script sftp host:dir` -- but function call syntax is what it is, which is to say, the function needs to be in head position as the command to be run at invocation time.

Comment: @OddKviteberg, ...so the only way you're going to make `sftp host:dir $file` look like it works is by changing it to `eval "sftp host:dir $file"` -- and as described in the BashFAQ #48 link above, that opens up a whole host of security risks / potential bugs. If you have a good reason for what you're asking for, _expand your question to describe that good reason_ so we can try to find a solution that satisfies the underlying constraints.

Comment: `stfp host:dir "$file"` would work fine with [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/3776858).

Comment: @Cyrus, for a very risky value of "fine", one that includes letting malicious filenames or herestrings execute arbitrary local code. And BTW, I think I point that out in the comment directly above yours (but with more caveats -- caveats I'd argue it's irresponsible to leave out of discussion)..

Comment: @Cyrus, ...btw, the decision to write `eval "sftp host:dir $file"` instead of `eval sftp host:dir "$file"` is a very deliberate one -- doing that makes it clear to readers that `eval` _combines its entire argument list into a single string_ before parsing that string. Otherwise, consequences that follow from that processing tend to get forgotten -- hence people being surprised (as they often are) that `eval printf ' - %s\n' $something` and `prinf ' - %s\n' $something` behave nothing at all like each other, even _before_ `$something` is reached.

Answer (score 2):

Unquoted here-docs **do** interpolate. Hence,

```
sftp host:dir <<EOF
put ${file@Q}
exit
EOF
```

I have put quotes around `$file` to catch the case that the filename contains spaces.

**UPDATE**: Incorporating the comment by Léa Gris.
Note: The syntax `@Q` is described in the bash man page under the heading *Parameter  transformation* :

> The  expansion  is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

While it means that quoting is done in a way that the input can be reused by bash, IMO it should be sufficient for the syntax in a ftp script as well.

Comment: `'$file'` will break when file name contains single quotes. With Bash 4+ you can expand variable with `${file@Q}` and it will automatically provide proper quoting if needed.

Comment: @LeaGris: That  it will break is what I wrote - but thank you for pointing out the idea with `@Q`. I didn't know this and will update my answer.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the quotes, as it will clash with the `${file@Q}`